# How to add/update/remove value in existing values list in redis cache using django

Tags: python-3.x, django, redis

I am storing data in redis as below:
key: `"fruitList"`
values: `[{"a": "apple", "id": 1}, {"b": "banana", "id": 2}, {"m": "mango", "id": 3}]`

to add following data, I used
`conn = cache.client.get_client()`
`conn.lpush(key, *values)`

Now I want to update/remove some element of a value eg. removing {"b": "banana", "id": 2} from values. I have huge list of values. How would I do that. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update list items but you can remove.

if you want to remove than use LREM command

```
conn = cache.client.get_client()
conn.lrem(key, *values)
```

The update can be done using LUA script as you would need an index for the item, you would have to use `LPOS` and `LSET` commands.